ACT-R Lisp dynamically create chunk
(defun creer-bagage (=poids =categorie)
  (let* ((timestamp (get-universal-time))
         (=id (format nil "~8d" (mod timestamp 100000000)))
         (=dimensions 
           (case =categorie
             (1 (list 3 3))  ;; Example dimensions for category 1
             (2 (list 6 2))  ;; Example dimensions for category 2
             (3 (list 6 3))  ;; Example dimensions for category 3
             (otherwise (error "Catégorie invalide : ~a" =categorie)))))
    
    ;; Création du chunk en mémoire déclarative
    )

    (add-dm (isa baggage
                 id =id
                 categorie =categorie
                 poids =poids
                 dimensions =dimensions
                 position nil
                 est-place nil))
                 
               ;   (define-chunks-fct (("new chunk") isa bagage id =id))
                 )

When running this code with parameters say 1 and 1 I have this  as result:
BAGGAGE0
   ID  =ID
   CATEGORIE  =CATEGORIE
   POIDS  =POIDS
   DIMENSIONS  =DIMENSIONS

So it does not pass the variables but instead treats them as strings. Please how do i fix it. Thanks

Where are definitions for isa and add-dm? Are you aware that (add-dm (isa baggage ;... occurs outside of the let form? It looks like you need to move the last parenth of the let form to be outside of the call to add-dm.

@adabsurdum I did that but still thesame result

What is add-dm and how is it defined? I am guessing that it is a macro.

add-dm is defined in act-r, it's used to create chunks and adds them in declarative memory

Please add context to explain what ACT-R is, for example add a link to https://github.com/asmaloney/ACT-R and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACT-R

From a quick glance at the documentation (I don't know anything about this framework), maybe you are expected to use add-dm-fct here (the function, not the macro)
